# Integration in an inequality

Tags: integration, inequality, taylor-expansion

Does integrating on both the sides of inequality with the same upper and lower limits with respect to same variable somehow affect the inequality.
I saw an example lets say,
Sin x < x ,x>0
Integrating repeatedly and along with some addition changes,makes the inequality to a Taylor series transform. Thus making the inequality an equality if we integrate infinite times w.r.t. X .

Comment: see the ineqaulity subsection here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral#Inequalities (I don't know how to directly link to it)

Comment: If $f(x)\le g(x)$ for $x\in [a,b]$, then $\int_a^b f(x)\,dx \le \int_a^b g(x)\,dx$

Comment: If I repeatedly integrate till infinite times then it may change to equality as in the case I had put in the question